# Render nested JSON items in React

Tags: reactjs

I'm new to React and I'm following a tutotial to learn how to fetch data from a public API.

I can render the "parent" items like the Title in this case, however I can't find a way to render the (nested) child items like Ratings. This is the error I'm getting "TypeError: movie.Ratings is undefined".

Here's the request outcome in JSON:

[image]

Here's my React code:

```
import React, { useEffect, useState } from "react";
import "./App.css";

function App() {

  const [movie, getMovie] = useState([]);

  useEffect(() => {
    const getData = async () => {
      const response = await fetch("https://www.omdbapi.com/?apikey=XXXXXXXX&t=Parasite");
      const json = await response.json();
      getMovie(json);
    };

    getData();

  }, []);

  return (
    <div className="App">
      <ul>
        <li>{movie.Title}</li>
        {movie.Ratings.map(Score => (
          <li>{Score.Source}</li>
        ))}
      </ul>
    </div>
  );

}

export default App
```

Comment: do you have some error? or what result do you want to get?

Comment: but you're rendering the ratings

Comment: I'm sorry, I forgot to include the error. This is the error I'm getting "TypeError: movie.Ratings is undefined". I'll update the question.

Comment: you need to render the component if movie && movie.Ratings are defined

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can add ? (optional chaining) to only to map if there is movie

```
 {movie.Ratings?.map(Score => (
      <>
      <li>{Score.Source}</li>
      <li>{Score.Value}</li>
      </>
    ))}
```

Comment: Thank you Dipesh. As mentioned, I'm new to React but this looks very elegant and simpler. This worked but how would you render Value as well, under each correspoding Source using this method?

Comment: Nevermind Dipesh, I just figured it out. I can simply use "<li>{Score.Source}: {Score.Value}</li>".

Comment: yeah.You can do in either way as you prefer :)

Comment: I think simply adding "?" (optional chaining) to only to map if there is movie as you suggested in your answer was the easiest and cleanest way to solve this problem. I'm choosing your answer. Thank you Dipesh.

Comment: Great to help you brother :)

Comment: I'm trying to render nested json objects that can be either a single object or array.  Is there a way to test if an item key exists, then if it's an array use map, else initialize a single react element. It there a better way. I was thinking in terms of a factory design pattern.                                                                                                                       {json.item?Array.isArray(json.item)?.map( (v) => ( </Item data={...} key={..} /> ):( </Item data={...} key={..} />)}

Answer (score 1):

There are a few things I notice

`const [movie, getMovie] = useState([]);`
You are initializing this as an array of `movie` it should be
`const [movie, getMovie] = useState({});`

```
function App() {

  const [movie, getMovie] = useState({});

  useEffect(() => {
    const getData = async () => {
      const response = await fetch("https://www.omdbapi.com/?apikey=XXXXXXXX&t=Parasite");
      const json = await response.json();
      getMovie(json);
    };

    getData();

  }, []);

  if (!movie.Ratings || movie.Ratings.length === 0) return null;

  return (
    <div className="App">
       <ul>
         <li>{movie.Title}</li>
         {movie.Ratings.map(score => (
           <li>{score.Source}</li>
         ))}
      </ul>
    </div>
  );
}
```

Or the return block can be written this way too without the if

```
return (
    <div className="App">
       <ul>
         <li>{movie.Title}</li>
         {movie.Ratings && movie.Ratings.map(score => (
           <li>{score.Source}</li>
         ))}
      </ul>
    </div>
  );
```

Comment: Thanks for your help Hendrix. I just tried your amends and now I'm getting "TypeError: movie.map is not a function".

Comment: Thank you, this works. But does that means I'll have to repeat "if (!movie.Ratings || movie.Ratings.length === 0) return null;" for every nested items I want to render?

Comment: I’ve added an alternative way too, depends how you wish to do it.